# Use Gensim or other python LDA packages to use trained LDA model from Mallet

Tags: gensim, lda, mallet

I have an LDA model trained through Mallet in Java. Three files are generated from the Mallet LDA model, which allow me to run the model from files and infer the topic distribution of a new text.

Now I would like to implement a Python tool which is able to infer a topic distribution given a new text, based on the trained LDA model. I do not want to re-trained the LDA model in Python. Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to load the trained Mallet LDA model into Gensim or any other python LDA package. If so, how can I do it?

Thanks for any answers or comments.

Answer (score 1):

In short yes you can!  That is what is nice about using mallet is that once it is run you don't have to go through and relabel topics.  I'm doing something very similar - I'll post my code below with a few helpful links.  Once your model is trained save the notebook widget state and you'll be free to run your model on new and different data-sets with the same topic allocation.  This code includes a test and validation set.  Make sure you've downloaded mallet and java then try this:

```html
# future bridges python 2 and 3
from __future__ import print_function

# pandas works with data structures, data manipulation, and analysis specifically for numerical tables, and series like 
# the csv we are using here today
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Gensim unsupervised topic modeling, natural language processing, statistical machine learning
import gensim
# convert a document to a list of tolkens
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
# remove stopwords - words that are not telling: "it" "I" "the" "and" ect.
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
# corpus iterator 
from gensim import corpora, models

# nltk - Natural Language Toolkit
# lemmatized — words in third person are changed to first person and verbs in past and future tenses are changed 
# into present.
# stemmed — words are reduced to their root form.
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer, SnowballStemmer
from nltk.stem.porter import *

# NumPy - multidimensional arrays, matrices, and high-level mathematical formulas
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2018)

import os
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
from pathlib import Path
import codecs
import logging

import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

# Gensim
import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel

# spacy for lemmatization
import spacy

# Plotting tools
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim  # don't skip this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Enable logging for gensim - optional
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.ERROR)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)

data = pd.read_csv('YourData.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1");
data_text = data[['Preprocessed Document or your comments column title']]
data_text['index'] = data_text.index
documents = data_text

# Create functions to lemmatize stem, and preprocess

# turn beautiful, beautifuly, beautified into stem beauti 
def lemmatize_stemming(text):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    return stemmer.stem(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(text, pos='v'))

# parse docs into individual words ignoring words that are less than 3 letters long
# and stopwords: him, her, them, for, there, ect since "their" is not a topic.
# then append the tolkens into a list
def preprocess(text):
    result = []
    for token in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text):
        newStopWords = ['yourStopWord1', 'yourStopWord2']
        if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and token not in newStopWords and len(token) > 3:
            nltk.bigrams(token)
            result.append(lemmatize_stemming(token))
    return result

# gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS

# look at a random row 4310 and see if things worked out
# note that the document created was already preprocessed

doc_sample = documents[documents['index'] == 4310].values[0][0]
print('original document: ')
words = []
for word in doc_sample.split(' '):
    words.append(word)
print(words)
print('\n\n tokenized and lemmatized document: ')
print(preprocess(doc_sample))

# let’s look at ten rows passed through the lemmatize stemming and preprocess

documents = documents.dropna(subset=['Preprocessed Document'])
processed_docs = documents['Preprocessed Document'].map(preprocess)
processed_docs[:10]

# we create a dictionary of all the words in the csv by iterating through
# contains the number of times a word appears in the training set.

dictionary_valid = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(processed_docs[20000:])
count = 0
for k, v in dictionary_valid.iteritems():
    print(k, v)
    count += 1
    if count > 30:
        break
        
 # we create a dictionary of all the words in the csv by iterating through
# contains the number of times a word appears in the training set.

dictionary_test = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(processed_docs[:20000])
count = 0
for k, v in dictionary_test.iteritems():
    print(k, v)
    count += 1
    if count > 30:
        break
        
# we want to throw out words that are so frequent that they tell us little about the topic 
# as well as words that are too infrequent >15 rows then keep just 100,000 words

dictionary_valid.filter_extremes(no_below=15, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000)

# we want to throw out words that are so frequent that they tell us little about the topic 
# as well as words that are too infrequent >15 rows then keep just 100,000 words

dictionary_test.filter_extremes(no_below=15, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000)

# the words become numbers and are then counted for frequency
# consider a random row 4310 - it has 8 words word indexed 2 shows up once
# preview the bag of words

bow_corpus_valid = [dictionary_valid.doc2bow(doc) for doc in processed_docs]
bow_corpus_valid[4310]

# the words become numbers and are then counted for frequency
# consider a random row 4310 - it has 8 words word indexed 2 shows up once
# preview the bag of words

bow_corpus_test = [dictionary_test.doc2bow(doc) for doc in processed_docs]
bow_corpus_test[4310]

# same thing in more words

bow_doc_4310 = bow_corpus_test[4310]
for i in range(len(bow_doc_4310)):
    print("Word {} (\"{}\") appears {} time.".format(bow_doc_4310[i][0], 
                                               dictionary_test[bow_doc_4310[i][0]], 
bow_doc_4310[i][1]))

mallet_path = 'C:/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet.bat'

ldamallet_test = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow_corpus_test, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary_test)

result = (ldamallet_test.show_topics(num_topics=20, num_words=10,formatted=False))
for each in result:
    print (each)
    
mallet_path = 'C:/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet.bat'

ldamallet_valid = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow_corpus_valid, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary_valid)

result = (ldamallet_valid.show_topics(num_topics=20, num_words=10,formatted=False))
for each in result:
    print (each)
    
# Show Topics
for idx, topic in ldamallet_test.print_topics(-1):
   print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, topic))
   
# Show Topics
for idx, topic in ldamallet_valid.print_topics(-1):
   print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, topic))
   
# check out the topics - 30 words - 20 topics

ldamallet_valid.print_topics(idx, 30)

# check out the topics - 30 words - 20 topics

ldamallet_test.print_topics(idx, 30)

# Compute Coherence Score
coherence_model_ldamallet_valid = CoherenceModel(model=ldamallet_valid, texts=processed_docs, dictionary=dictionary_valid, coherence='c_v')
coherence_ldamallet_valid = coherence_model_ldamallet_valid.get_coherence()
print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_ldamallet_valid)

# Compute Coherence Score
coherence_model_ldamallet_test = CoherenceModel(model=ldamallet_test, texts=processed_docs, dictionary=dictionary_test, coherence='c_v')
coherence_ldamallet_test = coherence_model_ldamallet_test.get_coherence()
print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_ldamallet_test)
```

Look at 16: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/
This helped: https://rare-technologies.com/tutorial-on-mallet-in-python/
and this: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.html

I hope this helps and good luck :)